# JS: Can't use asynchronous clipboard API for pages that will be minimized or put in the background

Tags: javascript, html, clipboard, html5-clipboard-api

Example:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<body>
<script>

setInterval(myFunction, 1000);

function myFunction() {
  window.focus()
  navigator.clipboard.readText()
}

</script>
</body>
</html>
```

If the user has a different application or browser window/tab open, this page will throw a `DOMException: Document is not focused.` error every second.

I am trying to make a page that monitors my clipboard. I am hoping to be able to leave the page open on my second monitor while I use a different program (and I will be copying text from that program, hence the clipboard monitoring).

But it seems like it is not possible to use the clipboard API if the browser is going to be in the background.

Note that the example can be run in any Chromium based browser, all of which allow granting of clipboard read permission on a page by page basis. (In Firefox, only extensions can use this clipboard API.)

Is there any workaround? I am also having trouble with using `document.execCommand("paste")` for this same goal.